# He: Weight Initialization with ReLu, why zero-center?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

My question is about weight initialization with [He initialization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852) for Conv NN. I'm wondering why they set the mean to zero. I get that this might be related to easy math, zero-centering and occam's razor. But when looking at the ReLU function which is 0 at 0, this is not intuitive to me. Wouldn't it be better to set the mean to something like 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

The weights are sampled from a zero-centered distribution (e.g., Uniform, Normal), but the outputs of the activations are not zero-centered - and because of that they need some modification from the Glorot init to keep the variance the same across layers.

The whole point of ReLU's is that some outputs will be zeroed. So, I wouldn't want to put weights with a big positive mean (e.g., a 100), because then the network will have to spend many rounds training/learning to zero out the neurons that need to be zeroed out. Also remember that the ReLU outputs are always positive, so the weights must learn to become negative in that case (except for the 1st layer which interacts with the input data itself). Zero-centered sounds the most logical to me.